# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.CLOB cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, jdbc

```
public List<SeguimientoRelease> busqSegRelease() throws Exception{

    String fuenteTmp = "select s.query from sac_definicion_alerta s\n" +
                    "where s.codigo = (select p.valor from parametros_generales p where p.cod_parametro = 'SEGR_COD_Q')";

    Object[] fuente = poolsconect.consultar(fuenteTmp, 3);

    try {

        List<Object[]> itemSegR = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        List<SeguimientoRelease> itemsegRFilter = new ArrayList<>();

        SeguimientoRelease seguimientoRelease;



        itemSegR = poolsconect.conexionBDListar((String) fuente[0], 3);
        for (Iterator<Object[]> it = itemSegR.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Object[] objects = it.next();
            seguimientoRelease = new SeguimientoRelease();

            seguimientoRelease.setEn_Prueba((String) objects[1]);
            seguimientoRelease.setEn_produccion((String) objects[2]);
            String sDate1="31/12/1998";  
            Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(String.valueOf(objects[3]));  
            seguimientoRelease.setF_est_produccion(date1);
            date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(String.valueOf(objects[4]));  
            seguimientoRelease.setF_real_Produccion(date1);
            seguimientoRelease.setSol_pen_cierre((String) objects[5]);

            itemsegRFilter.add(seguimientoRelease);

        }
        return itemsegRFilter;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DaoSeguimientoRelease.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        return null;

    }

}
```

Este es el error:

> Grave:   java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.CLOB cannot be cast
>   to java.lang.String
>       at com.SEGR.Dao.DaoSeguimientoRelease.busqSegRelease(DaoSeguimientoRelease.java:142)
>       at com.SEGR.beans.BeansSeguimientoRelease.(BeansSeguimientoRelease.java:46)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
>       at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
>       at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
>       at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
>       at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
>       at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>       at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>       at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Tienes ahí varios casteos y uno o más de ellos no te funcionan (sospecho que este: `(String) objects[5]`) ya que el valor que es tratas de castear es de tipo CLOB y no es compatible con String, por lo que tienes que convertirlo explícitamente a String con `.toString()` o `String.valueOf()`. Fíjate que tienes algún ejemplo de `String.valueOf` que puedes reaprovechar para arreglar esos casteos que te están fallando.

Comment: brother esos casteos estan buen, necesito castear el clob que me trae la variable fuente y asi obtener el text que tiene el Query  ,que esta dentro de una tabla y que tiene otro query adentro

Comment: Muy bien no estarán porque te esta tirando una excepción

Comment: pero solo necesito castear el de fuente, solo ese